# How do I show that a functional $F$ is an element of $C_{L^2} [-1,1]^*$ and calculate its norm $||F||$?

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

Let $X =C_{L^2}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$ which is the space of continuous functions on the intervall [-1,1] which map to the real numbers, equipped with the $L^2$ inner product, and a functional $F:X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$F(x) = \int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt.$$ Show that $F \in C_{L^2}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})^*$ and calculate $||F||_{X^*}$.

I know that for $F$ to be an element of the dual space of $X$, $F$ must be linear and continuous. $F$ is linear because of the linearity of the integral and for it to be continuous it must be bounded. I tried to show that $F$ is bounded but I ran into problems because the integral limits are not the same as the limits of $X$. My idea was: $$|F(x)|=\Bigg|\int_{0}^{1}x(t)dt + \int_{-1}^{0}x(t)dt - \int_{-1}^{0}x(t)dt\Bigg|=\Bigg|\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\int_{-1}^{0}x(t)dt\Bigg|.$$ Then for a $y \in X$ defined by $y \equiv 1$ it follows: $$\Bigg|\int_{-1}^{1}x(t)dt-\int_{-1}^{0}x(t)dt\Bigg|=\Bigg|\langle x,y\rangle_{L^2[-1,1]} - \int_{-1}^{0}x(t)dt\Bigg|.$$ I know that by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that $$\langle x,y\rangle_{L^2[-1,1]} \le \Bigg(\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dt\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}\Bigg(\int_{-1}^{1}y^2dt\Bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt2\cdot||x||_{L^2[-1,1]}$$
Now if I could get rid of the integral in the absolute value I would be done but I don´t know how to progress from this point. I also have problems with calculating $||F||_{X^*}$ since $X$ isn´t a Hilbert space and therefore I can´t use the Riesz representation theorem. Please correct my where I´m wrong, help would be very much appreciated! Also I hope that everything is understandable since this is my first post and english isn´t my first language. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the space $C_{L^{2}}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $C_{L^2}([-1,1],\mathbb{R})$ is the space of continuous functions on the intervall [-1,1] which map to the real numbers, equipped with the $L^2$ inner product which is defined by $\langle x,y \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} x(t)y(t)dt $. Sorry, I forgot to add that to the question.

Comment: You mean $C_{L^{2}}([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$ is the subset of continuous functions that are in $L^{2}([-1,1])$?

Comment: Yes that shoud be the most precise description. I have encountered this question in my mathematical physics course I´m currently taking. We haven´t progressed too far yet and it only glosses over some functional analysis concepts, not in the most rigorous way, which is why I´m not too certain on all the different spaces and notations yet.

Comment: Since $x$ is continuous it is bounded and since $[-1,1]$ is closed $x$ is also integrable. Using this you can easily majorate $|F(x)|$.

Comment: $$ F(x)^2 =\left(\int_0^1x(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\right)^2 \le\int_0^1x(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t \le\int_{-1}^1x(t)^2\,\mathrm{d}t =\|x\|_{C_{L^2}[-1,1]}^2 $$ seems to indicate the norm is at most $1$. Showing it is $1$ should be simple.

Comment: Ah yes that seems logical, much better than my solution. I will think through the problem a bit more, but I think I got the gist of it now. Thank you both very much for your help!